# MongoDB BulkWrite Memory Cost

Tags: mongodb, go, memory-leaks, bulkinsert

I'm using the official `mongodb` driver for Go. I take a CSV and read it line by line till I reach 1000 lines, I then parse the data and insert it into the db. I assumed it'd take a constant memory as the data that goes to bulk write is always the same (1000 contacts). However, that is not the case as the memory increases significantly. Here's some data regarding the above query:

```
batchSize = 1000

Contacts - Memory consumed by bulkwrite
10k - 14 MB
20K - 30MB
30K - 59MB
40K - 137 MB
50K -241 MB
```

Can anyone explain why?

Here's the code:

```
func (c *csvProcessor) processCSV(r io.Reader, headerMap map[string]int, emailDB *mongo.Database) error {
    //some code...
    csvReader := csv.NewReader(r)
    for {
        eofReached, err := c.processCSVBatch(csvReader, emailHash, smsHash, headerMap, emailDB)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, "process CSV batch")
        }
        if eofReached {
            break
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (c *csvProcessor) processCSVBatch(csvReader *csv.Reader, emailHash map[string]*userData, smsHash map[string]*userData, headerMap map[string]int, emailDB *mongo.Database) (bool, error) {
    var insertUsers, updateUsers, deleteUsers []interface{}
    var isEOFReached bool
    for i := 0; i < processCSVBatchSize; i++ {
        line, err := csvReader.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                return false, errors.Wrap(err, "read from input")
            }
            isEOFReached = true
            break
        }
        //some code
        insert, update, delete := c.dataMerger.mergeData(
            c.parseUser(line, headerMap),
            emailHash[stringToMD5(line[headerMap["email"]])],
            smsHashVal,
        )
        if insert != nil {
            insertUsers = append(insertUsers, insert)
        }
        if update != nil {
            updateUsers = append(updateUsers, update)
        }
        if delete != nil {
            deleteUsers = append(deleteUsers, delete)
        }
    }
    //update DB
    err := c.mongoDBUserHandler.saveUsers(emailDB, insertUsers, updateUsers, deleteUsers)
    if err != nil {
        return false, errors.Wrap(err, "save users")
    }
    return isEOFReached, nil
}

func (m *mongoDBUserHandler) saveUsers(emailDB *mongo.Database, insert, update, delete []interface{}) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    // create the slice of write models
    var writes []mongo.WriteModel
    if len(insert) > 0 {
        writes = append(writes, m.getInsertWrites(insert)...)
    }
    if len(update) > 0 {
        writes = append(writes, m.getUpdateWrites(update)...)
    }
    if len(delete) > 0 {
        writes = append(writes, m.getDeleteWrites(delete)...)
    }
    if len(writes) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    // run bulk write
    _, err := emailDB.
        Collection(userCollection).
        BulkWrite(ctx, writes, options.BulkWrite().SetOrdered(false))
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "bulk write")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Can u share the code? Could be go runtime dynamic stack grows or goroutine heap alloc

Comment: do you configure the slice capacity ?

Comment: @mh-cbon a new slice is allocated each time we try to save the data to DB. You can refer to the code above.

Comment: @mh-cbon read the code again - it's all new slices for each 1000 row batch, so unless you can point out some other place where a slice might be growing unbounded, I don't see how that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

below are [copy](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy) in disguise:

```
    if len(insert) > 0 {
        writes = append(writes, m.getInsertWrites(insert)...)
    }
    if len(update) > 0 {
        writes = append(writes, m.getUpdateWrites(update)...)
    }
    if len(delete) > 0 {
        writes = append(writes, m.getDeleteWrites(delete)...)
    }
```

Very low hanging fruit: remove those lines above, change BulkWrite to accept `writes` as `interface{}` so that you can reuse **the same backing array**, that should save you some memory.